# Converting C array accesses to MIPS

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

The question is:

> Assume that the base address of the arrays `A` and `B` are in registers `$s6` and `$s7`, respectively.
>
> And the variables `f` and `g` are assigned to registers `$s0`, `$s1`, respectively.
>
> What is the corresponding MIPS assembly code for the following C code: `f = g - A[B[4]];`

My idea is:

```
lw $t0, 16($s7) # $t0 = B[4]
lw $t1, 64($s6) # $t1 = A[B[4]]
sub $s0, $s1, $t1 # $s0 = $s1 - $t1
```

I got wrong on this answer and I don't know why. Can someone help me on an idea or explanation, please?

Comment: `A[B[4]]` would imply that the `$t0` load result is part of the address for this load.  But it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Good attempt, but your code can't be right because `$t0` was loaded but never used. I'm also not sure where the number 64 came from, but basically that should be the value pulled from `B[4]`, `$t0`.

You might be confused by the nested array access `A[B[4]]`. Conceptually, this is using the value stored in `B[4]` as an index into `A`. It's better to expand that out and start with the single-operation-per-line C code:

```c
t0 = B[4];
t1 = A[t0];
f = g - t1;
```

Now it's easier to come up with:

```
lw $t0, 16($s7)    # B_val = B[4]
sll $t0, $t0, 2    # B_val *= 4
addu $t2, $t0, $s6 # A_offset = B_val + A_base
lw $t1, ($t2)      # A_val = A[A_offset]
sub $s0, $s1, $t1  # f = g - A_val
```

Here, I assume the `B` value needs to be multiplied by 4.

You can always write a program to validate your work (at least, after the exam):

```
    .data
A: .word 1, 1, 1, 1, 24
B: .word 1, 1, 1, 1, 4

    .text
main:
    la $s6 A           # A_base
    la $s7 B           # B_base
    li $s1, 42         # g = 42

    lw $t0, 16($s7)    # B_val = B[4]
    sll $t0, $t0, 2    # B_val *= 4
    addu $t2, $t0, $s6 # A_offset = B_val + A_base
    lw $t1, ($t2)      # A_val = A[A_offset]
    sub $s0, $s1, $t1  # f = g - A_val

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $s0
    syscall            # => should be 42 - 24 = 18

    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: Yup, that's more or less what a C compiler does: https://godbolt.org/z/bMeaebze1. (taking args since the question specifies values are already in registers).  (Assuming like you did that these are arrays of signed `int`.)  But note that pointer math should use `addu`, not `add`: you don't want to trap on signed overflow if the `A[]` happens to span the middle of the address space, and `A + B[4]` changes the MSB of the address. (You almost never want `add` or `sub`, except maybe for debugging when you expect no overflow - C compilers don't use them, although you *could* for signed int `-` here)